# In Karate DSL, How do I verify the field names within the response without caring about what their values are

Tags: java, cucumber, karate

I could not find anything in the documentation regarding this but I am trying to verify the field names within a response. I do not care what their values are. What would be the proper way to do this using Karate DSL? My focus is on the response match below.

```
Given path 'serviceRequests', 'tasks'
And param view = 'short' * header Authorization = 'Bearer ' + Token
When method get
Then status 200
And match response == { page:  'i-dont-care', total: 'i-dont-care'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this section of the doc: [Ignore or Validate](https://github.com/intuit/karate#ignore-or-validate)

```
And match response == { page: '#ignore', total: '#notnull' }
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. is there a way to wrap the response matches to more than one line? When I attempt to do this, it is not being recognized. there are a lot of fields to validate. And match response $.content[0] == { srId: '#string', taskId: '#string', facilityId: '#string', taskStatusCode: '#string',  etc. etc. etc.}

Comment: Disregard my above question. I found in the documentation you can wrap them in """ quotations. So something like And match response $.content[0] == """ json request """

Comment: @AbeinatorEmancipator - yes. you can also read from files: https://github.com/intuit/karate#reading-files